# How to show tree branches for files in Windows tree command output?

Tags: windows-7, windows, tree

I am using the flags `/a` and `/f`.

I want to make the `|` and `---` appear for subdirectories too.  At the moment, it lists files in sub directories but does not show the `|` or `---`

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, have you looked into a `tree` replacement, or writing an application or script to do the same thing?

Comment: I did this a couple of years back.  Just wish I remembered how, now! lol

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing a bit of code you might want to take a look at Eric Lippert's Blog he had a coding challange to do something similar to do what you are looking for in his post [Old school tree display](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/old-school-tree-display) he also posted his solution [Eric's solution for old school tree dumping](https://web.archive.org/web/20130428231154/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/09/eric-s-solution-for-old-school-tree-dumping.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to parse the output from `tree` and replace the blank spaces before files. The simplest way to achieve that is to use a regex in PowerShell like below

```powershell
tree /a /f |% { $_ -creplace '^(([ |]   )*)[| ]   ([^+|\\ ])', '$1+---$3' }
```

It works by matching the first N folder levels (whose representation contains a space or a `|` character followed by 3 spaces) with `^(([ |]   )*)`, and then checking for a possible vertical line in the last level following by 3 spaces and a character in the file name: `[| ]   ([^+|\\ ])`

One small limitation of this is that the last file won't be shown with a "rounded" `\` corner. Sample output:

```
PS C:\Windows\Boot\DVD> tree /f
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 74FF-D5FA
C:.
├───EFI
│   │   BCD
│   │   boot.sdi
│   │
│   └───en-US
│           efisys.bin
│           efisys_noprompt.bin
│
└───PCAT
    │   BCD
    │   boot.sdi
    │   etfsboot.com
    │
    └───en-US
            bootfix.bin

PS C:\Windows\Boot\DVD> tree /a /f |% {
    $_ -creplace '^(([ |]   )*)[| ]   ([^+|\\ ])', '$1+---$3' }
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 74FF-D5FA
C:.
+---EFI
|   +---BCD
|   +---boot.sdi
|   |
|   \---en-US
|       +---efisys.bin
|       +---efisys_noprompt.bin
|
\---PCAT
    +---BCD
    +---boot.sdi
    +---etfsboot.com
    |
    \---en-US
        +---bootfix.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to make `tree` output the `---` before file names so you have to use some other `tree` implementations. Here's one in PowerShell

```powershell
param(
    [string]$Path,
    [Alias("F")]
    [switch]$ShowFilesFirst,
    [Alias("A")]
    [switch]$UseAscii,
    [Alias("D")]
    [switch]$ShowDirectoriesOnly
)

$BRANCHES = @(
    [PsCustomObject]@{ First = "├───"; Last = "└───"; Dir = "│   " },
    [PsCustomObject]@{ First = "+---"; Last = "\---"; Dir = "|   " }
)

function Show-Files([System.IO.FileInfo[]]$files, [string]$prefix, [bool]$showCorner) {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Length; ++$i) {
        $f = $files[$i]
        if (($i -eq $files.Length - 1) -and $showCorner) {
            echo ($prefix + $BRANCHES[$UseAscii.IsPresent].Last  + $f.Name)
        } else {
            echo ($prefix + $BRANCHES[$UseAscii.IsPresent].First + $f.Name)
        }
    }
}

function Show-Tree([string]$path, [string]$prefix) {
    $folders = @(Get-ChildItem -Directory $path)
    $files   = @(Get-ChildItem -File      $path)

    if ($ShowFilesFirst -and -not $ShowDirectoriesOnly) {
        $showFileCorner = ($folders.Length -eq 0) -or (-not $ShowFilesFirst)
        Show-Files $files $prefix $showFileCorner
    }
    
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $folders.Length; ++$i) {
        $d = $folders[$i]
        $showDirCorner = ($files.Length -eq 0) -or $ShowFilesFirst
        if (($i -eq $folders.Length - 1) -and $showDirCorner) {
            echo ($prefix + $BRANCHES[$UseAscii.IsPresent].Last  + $d.Name)
            Show-Tree -path $d.FullName -prefix "$prefix    "
        } else {
            echo ($prefix + $BRANCHES[$UseAscii.IsPresent].First + $d.Name)
            Show-Tree -path $d.FullName -prefix ($prefix + $BRANCHES[$UseAscii.IsPresent].Dir)
        }
    }
    
    if (-not $ShowFilesFirst -and -not $ShowDirectoriesOnly) {
        Show-Files $files $prefix $true
    }
}

if ($Path -eq "") {
    (Get-Location).Path
} else {
    echo $Path
}
Show-Tree -path $Path -prefix ""
```

Just save it as `tree.ps1` and run. Parameters:

- `-Path`: path to the tree, optional
- `-ShowFilesFirst`/`-F`: print files before folders. By default folders will be printed first
- `-UseAscii`/`-A`: use ASCII characters only instead of Unicode
- `-ShowDirectoriesOnly`/`-D`: don't print files, same as the default `tree` behavior

Sample output:

```
PS C:\Windows\Boot\DVD> C:\tree.ps1
C:\Windows\Boot\DVD
├───EFI
│   ├───en-US
│   │   ├───efisys.bin
│   │   └───efisys_noprompt.bin
│   ├───BCD
│   └───boot.sdi
└───PCAT
    ├───en-US
    │   └───bootfix.bin
    ├───BCD
    ├───boot.sdi
    └───etfsboot.com
PS C:\Windows\Boot\DVD> C:\tree.ps1 -A -ShowFilesFirst
C:\Windows\Boot\DVD
+---EFI
|   +---BCD
|   +---boot.sdi
|   \---en-US
|       +---efisys.bin
|       \---efisys_noprompt.bin
\---PCAT
    +---BCD
    +---boot.sdi
    +---etfsboot.com
    \---en-US
        \---bootfix.bin
```